# How to migrate ubuntu to an ssd when /home is encrypted with ecryptfs?

Tags: mount, encryption, ssd, ecryptfs

I discovered this topic '[How to migrate an encrypted LVM install to a new disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260777/how-to-migrate-an-encrypted-lvm-install-to-a-new-disk)' which was useful for creating lvm volumes on my new SSD. Nevertheless, my original Ubuntu 14.04 has just a /home encrypted (with ecryptfs) and the part showing the decrypt of /dev/sda5 is not appropriate to my case.

I would like to know in which order do the things, I mean, here is my lsblk :

```
stee@stee-OptiPlex-760:~$ lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0   149G  0 disk  
├─sda1                  8:1    0  89,8G  0 part  /
├─sda2                  8:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5                  8:5    0     2G  0 part  
  └─cryptswap1 (dm-0) 252:0    0     2G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I can't see where is my home, on sda1 or sda5 ??

Do i need to copy my crypted swap ?

Here is my /etc/fstab :

```
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=eef61317-fd02-4eee-85ce-8a00b20ef131 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#UUID=da79fe68-814e-48e0-9fe8-bac41f1ffcbb none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

ANd my /etc/crypttab :

```
cryptswap1 /dev/sda5 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

Ubuntuly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eCryptfs doesn't encrypt an entire partition like LUKS/dm-crypt does, your home is stored (encrypted) in a regular folder, apparently somewhere on your sda1 root partition in your case.

Making a regular backup of your home while you're logged in (and it's mounted/decrypted) would be a good method to migrate it to another location (keeping the backup copy encrypted along the way, if desired).

Or investigate the `ecryptfs-recover-private` command/script, to view/copy your encrypted home if it's not automatically mounted/decrypted, after migrating perhaps.

Comment: Also (after you backup the encrypted data), don't just copy/migrate your data to the SSD. You want a clean install of Ubuntu that has been configured (at install time) to use SSD as primary media.

Comment: I'll give 'ecryptfs-recover-private' a try once booted on my usb key.<br>I guess finally that my cryptswap isn't necessary to recover and in fact i was going in the bad direction. I keep you informed. Thanks

Comment: @david6 : yeah it's my goal, switching from my old sata to ssd primary drive, i already made it on my laptop but starting from scratch, i.e : reinstalling all the stuff, hope this new way will make it :)

Comment: Finally, i formated my whole ssd to create a big sdb1 partition + an extended of 4G. Then through gparted, i just copied sda1 to sdb1 and made a good coffee til it accomplished (by the way my crypted home went in sdb1), then started the tricky part when it came to change uuid of sdb1 (take a look here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/132079/how-do-i-change-uuid-of-a-disk-to-whatever-i-want). I then restarted and faced a 'time-has-stopped' grub prompt from which i started thanks to this grateful post : https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/.

Comment: my lsblk :</br> NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT</br>
sda                     8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk</br>
├─sda1                  8:1    0  96,7G  0 part  /</br>
├─sda2                  8:2    0     1K  0 part </br>
└─sda5                  8:5    0     2G  0 part </br>
  └─cryptswap1 (dm-0) 252:0    0     2G  0 crypt [SWAP]</br>
sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  </br>