# How to change /home to a new encrypted LVM partition

Tags: partitioning, encryption, lvm

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and chose the option to remove all and set an encrypted LVM(I have a backup of all my data).

I have 1 SSD(`/dev/sda`) and 1 HDD(`/dev/sdb`).
What the installer did:
It set LVM for `/dev/sda` and that's all, it didn't touch `/dev/sdb`.

What I try to do and can't find info about(there is info on what I try to do but not with LVM + encryption - at least from what I could find):
- Remove encryption from the root `/`(that's not that important, but I don't need security for that data, I would like performance)
- Set `/home`, `/var` and `/tmp` to be on the encrypted HDD(`/dev/sdb`) - this is the main issue
- Remove swap from the SSD

Relevant `fdisk -l` output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 119,2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb607a342

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 250068991 249067522 118,8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 250068991 249067520 118,8G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 698,7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3E77BD28-907B-4CDD-B5A9-5886A8E3CF74

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 1465149134 1465147087 698,7G Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: 118,8 GiB, 127520473088 bytes, 249063424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 110,8 GiB, 119000793088 bytes, 232423424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 7,9 GiB, 8493465600 bytes, 16588800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Any guru out there? :)

Comment: I found something that might be helpful(I'll try later): http://askubuntu.com/questions/260777/how-to-migrate-an-encrypted-lvm-install-to-a-new-disk

Comment: I managed to remove the swap and add it back to root, and also managed to add the HDD with LVM + encryption.
But after a restart I observed that the boot is slow after decrypting the volume, so I decided now to go for a Ubuntu Server install(makes it easy to set-up LVM) and then "sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop -y"

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: @guntbert Well, those were comments/remarks that are not important to the question itself...
As for my issue, I solved it the next day and it sits on my "to do" list for a pretty long time to write a detailed answer on how somebody else can solve this same issue(I have it in a raw draft in my email).
I would also like to remark that it saddens me that nobody came with any help. If I would of been a user that has no experience with Linux, I would of sat even now with a broken system...