# Moving Kubuntu from hdd to ssd

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem, ssd

I bought a new SSD to install it in my HTPC. Before, I had an HDD with Kubuntu. I would need to copy the files from the / partition from HDD to SSD.
To do this, I booted from the Kubuntu livecd, mounted both disks and copied all the files over:

```
sudo cp -ax /media/hd /media/ssd
```

Following this answer: [How to move Ubuntu to an SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40372/how-to-move-ubuntu-to-an-ssd), I´m stuck with this step:

**Then you just need to edit the /etc/fstab on the ssd to point to the new fs UUID ( you can look it up with blkid )**.

I don´t know how to do it because if I try to edit the /etc/fstab on the SSD, it gives me an error telling me that there is no such a file or directory. I try this approach:

```
sudo nano /media/ssd/etc/fstab
```

because I mounted the ssd on /media/ssd in order to copy the / partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you pick up some cloning software about $20, you can move everything over to your SSD.  All you need to do is have your keys for any licensed software.