# Ubuntu 14.4 LTS On Other HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

Please Help Me

Hello and Good Evening,

1st...

I had a Computer With 80 GB SATA HDD. So I recently Upgrade to ubuntu 14.4LTS. But Somehow My PC is Going to be Shutdown.

2nd

I bought a New Computer Which is AMD APU, MSI Motherboard where 250 SATA HDD with Windows 8.1 Installed. So now I took the 80 GB SATA HDD From my old PC which Loaded With Ubuntu 14.4 LTS and Installed In my New Computer But When I tried to Make the Ubuntu HDD first piority for boot in BIOS but only shows one USB HDD and Primary Windows HDD.

But I seleted USB HDD Thought It would be UBUNTU but when I boot it goes to Windows Directly I did Many Changes But Nothing.

" Please Help My Development Environment Is In Ubuntu "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused about which hard drive is usb and which isn't, but if it were me I'd try to install a fresh Ubuntu onto whichever HD is physically inside the new computer (not a fan of USB HD's for a system drive, not as reliable it seems). Using a Ubuntu live iso/cd/usb, and with the old USB HD not even plugged in.

Then with the new Ubuntu in the new HD & new computer working, you could move your $HOME from the old drive onto the new Ubuntu (if you want to keep your old settings).

Here's a quick guide to copying an old home folder to a new one, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving#Copy_.2BAC8-home_to_the_New_Partition It's basically copy the files with the same permissions & owner (but the owner can be changed with `chown` later anyway). A file manager like Nautilus or Thunar or any one should work fine instead of `rsync` too.

Plugging an old HD (with an old OS) into a new computer doesn't always work, the hardware differences could be too great. (An 80GB HD could be from a 10 year old single cpu computer, the AMD APU's are 3 years old or so & could be 8 core?)

---

And this page has info on migrating Ubuntu from one HD to a new HD, only on the same computer. It might work for your case, but because of the hardware changes it may not be ideal https://askubuntu.com/a/40454/129271

Comment: Yes I am sorry to Not to Clear, Thing is that HDD From Old Computer Isn't any USB HDD But It is Showing Only On BIOS as USB. Ok Can you give me Process How can I keep My Old Settings after fresh Installation Of Ubuntu. Because I Googled It Seems There is Some EFEI System MBR Matching Somethings, So How can I Keep My OLD UBUNTU SETTINGS AFTER NEW INSTALLATION???

Comment: Most of your program settings (config files in "hidden" folders & files that start with a `.` and regular folders ) are stored in your home folder, it's usually in `/home/[user]` you copy those from the old HD into the new system's `/home` (maybe running `adduser` first to set up the user & password), then you should be able to log in as the "new" "old" user.

Comment: You're welcome. It can be a little tricky switching to different hardware, and it's good to have a few options to try if one doesn't work good enough.

Comment: Hello Thank you I managed to Installed The HDD With Boot Rpair Disk. Now I have Choose Between Win & Ubuntu.