# Hdd to ssd (laptop ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Dear fellow Ubuntu appreciaters

I'm an absolute novice and will probably use the Ubuntu 14.04 OS soon.
I'm considering to change the 5OOGB HDD with a 250 SSD drive for some faster handling. Having read some basic research it should be possible. However I'm doubting as a novice I will succeed to transfer the pre installed files to the new SSD drive and run Ubuntu. 
There can only use one harddrive so need to copy the files to the ssd before making the change i guess...
Any experiences for a Ubuntu novice are highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move Ubuntu to an SSD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40372/how-to-move-ubuntu-to-an-ssd)

Comment: I did the same thing as the instructions at the link above, but I used gparted (already installed on a live CD) to copy my partitions, and I did boot-repair (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc) to fix my boot on the new disk. If boot-repair doesn't work you might have reinstalled on the old HDD. Don't forget to make your BIOS boot on the new SSD.

Comment: If you haven't got nothing personal on the hard drive, why not just reinstall?

Comment: good comment, thx! I also thought about this but found the following information on the ubuntu website: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201411-16163/

"Standard images of Ubuntu may not work at all on the system or may not work well, though Canonical and computer manufacturers will try to certify the system with future standard releases of Ubuntu."

Answer (score 1):

Clone the HDD using CloneZilla http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone,   then run gparted to resize the disk.

To resize a partition:

1.- Select a partition.

2.- Choose: Partition → Resize/Move

3.- Adjust the size of the disk.

4.- Click Resize/Move.