# Moving from dual-boot to single

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I've installed Ubuntu on a secondary HDD for dual-booting with Windows 10 on my primary SSD.

I've now decided that I want to make the switch completely and have Ubuntu booting on my SSD (and removing Windows 10).

How might I go about doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move Ubuntu to an SSD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40372/how-to-move-ubuntu-to-an-ssd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [gparted](http://gparted.org/download.php)

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

and first delete the Windows partition and then extend Ubuntu's partition or use [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm)(Logical Volume management) in order to create logical volumes.

Make sure after that you run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Comment: This isn't quite a full solution. OP wants at least `/boot` to be moved to the SSD Windows was on. I'm not downvoting (in fact, I'm upvoting), because this is a great answer. It's just missing a suggestion on how to go about getting Ubuntu to boot from the SSD, but have data on the HDD.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I agree with you. My answer should have those details also which you mentioned. I assumed that while he is following the steps i mentioned he/she will be able to figure out having /boot on first(primary SSD). boot-repair will provide that recommendation/finding also.

Comment: I don't think it will. `boot-repair` repairs GRUB. Even if that is on the SSD, it still won't have the Ubuntu core on the SSD. The OS will be on the HDD still. It would probably be best for OP to back up data, format both drives and start fresh. Choose the Something Else option in the installer, mount `/` on the SSD and `/home` on the HDD.