# Move Ubuntu 16.04 to a SSD from HDD occurring error, no ssd shown in grub menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, uefi, ssd

I was using an 1TB hdd with uefi boot window10(updated from 7) and ubuntu 16.04 on it.It worked fine.I first installed windows,and then parted 120gb free space for ubuntu,then I installed ubuntu just by setting installing alongside other operating systems in the installation menu and that's done.
I'm not sure if the grub was installed in the windows efi partition or somewhere else, because ubuntu just have two partition, / and the swap.

After that, I got a ssd. I followed the instruction on this page, http://blog.oaktreepeak.com/2012/03/move_your_linux_installation_t.html

and this page:

[How to move Ubuntu to an SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40372/how-to-move-ubuntu-to-an-ssd)

Copying system from hdd to ssd was ok. I think the problem is with GRUB.
I tried both terminal the boot-repair, but in vain.
What confuses me is: I find these lines in grub customer
[grub customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgYVC.png)

My ssd is sda. As shown in the picture,it seems ok. But when I boot,I can not find anything about sda. All is about sdb(my hdd).

In details,I created /boot and / ext4 partition andcopied the files from my origin ubuntu accordingly. Then I created a 2mb bios-grub partition just because I failed with grub-install /dev/sda.(I followed a post

,telling me to create this to avoid "this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won’t be possible" error.

I did this, and succeeded. But still boot from hdd,instead of ssd. So I tried the boot-repair,both recommended repair and advanced(when using advanced,I set ubuntu on ssd as default boot and set to fix grub on sdbX(my windows efi partition)),after that, I still faced the same problem.The strange thing is,I cannot mnt my ssd on ubuntu hdd(still can boot).

Thanks in advance for any reply from you.:)

Comment: You need to create an EFI system partition on the new drive and install grub there.  As it is, your old hd is still booting, and the first entries are for it, and the ones for sda are to boot the install it detected on your ssd instead.

Comment: I kind of have an oddball question  .. have you checked your UEFI to see if its using the proper boot loader? I had a Windows issue once when restoring a backup .. it said the drive wasn't bootable and I thought the restore failed .. but it turned out that in my UEFI I wasn't set to the Windows boot loader so it was trying to boot to another drive... maybe you keep booting to the hard drive because your UEFI is set to use that bootloader even tho you may have one on the ssd. It may not be anything like this but I figured I would through it out .. worth checking I guess

Comment: Thank you John. Actually I enabled uefi mode with legacy support. So I was able to press F12 to select which device I want to boot from. The question is still there.  I tried psusi's advice and then I got two grub---one from hdd and another ssd(But with no sda at all), I can tell because I set a nice background on the hdd grub. :P What can I do now?

Comment: Hi psusi,I added an efi partition and set boot(efi) using Gparted. Then I got two grub,one from the ssd,another from the hdd. But the ssd one still has no entry for sda....What should I do now ?thanks...   Oh, and one more thing,the grub was getting terribly slow since yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify if you still have both hard drive and SSD installed in the machine?
Did you change the boot priority in your BIOS?  If the Hdd is still higher in the boot order than the SSD, then it will boot from that first and not even look at the SSD.

Comment: Yes,thank you, I still have both hard drive. But I change the boot prority in BIOS,I am quite sure about that(actually I always select pressing F12). Any other advice please?

Answer (score 0):

OK, It's eventually resolved. I resized my sda so now it only has one partition which is sda1. (before that I copied files on boot partition to /boot)The swap is the old swap area on hdd. Then I used **boot-repair** tool again.This time it solved the problem. Be sure to open a terminal before the  operation because it may probably cannot run during the repair. All I needed to do was copy the code boot-repair indicated and paste into terminal and run and click next, pretty simple. Then I finally boot on ssd.