# Move ubuntu to ssd elaboration

Tags: partitioning, mount, ssd, fstab

Hello I want to follow the steps of [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40372/how-to-move-ubuntu-to-an-ssd), but I don't understand the part about the fstab. I don't have the 50 cursed reputation points so I can't comment in order to ask the person who answered the question, to elaborate on that part.

So can anyone help me? what do I have to change inside the fstab? And what blkid does? cause when I typed it on terminal I got nothing back.

Comment: Try `sudo blkid`, it should show available partitions and their UUIDs. UUIDs are also what you'll need to change in fstab.

Comment: oh sudo... ok now it show some things. but how do I change it? I mean what id goes where?

Comment: New UUIDs should replace the old ones. New partitions on the SSD will have different UUIDs, you'll find them with `sudo blkid`, and put them into fstab in place of the old ones.

Comment: Often easier just to do a new install & copy /home and/or data into that new install. Only if you made custom hardware settings changes may you need those from /etc. All your user settings are in /home, most in . or hidden files & folders.

Comment: If I just fresh install and copy my home folder I will have the same configuration as now? Or will I have to install everything again?