# /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 after moving ubuntu to ssd

Tags: hard-drive, 17.10, ssd

I moved my ubuntu installation from my HDD to my SSD, but now my permissions seem to be messed up.. For example; i can't run my installed Chrome browser anymore, and running sudo gives me the sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set error.

I've used this manual to move my installation to my SSD; https://askubuntu.com/a/40454

Any idea what's going wrong?

I've also already tried to reboot in recovery mode and chown / chmod the /user/bin/sudo file / directory as root..

**Edit:**

As i said, i've used this manual to move my installation to my SSD: https://askubuntu.com/a/40454

The instructions were as follows:

## 1) Copying files

You want to copy the FILES, not the whole partition ( including its free space ), so you don't need to resize the partition first. Boot from the livecd and mount both the HD and SSD ( after formatting a partition on the SSD of course ), then copy all of the files over:

```
sudo cp -ax /media/hd /media/ssd
```

Use the correct names for the hd and ssd mount points of course. Then you just need to edit the /etc/fstab on the ssd to point to the new fs UUID ( you can look it up with blkid ). Finally you need to install grub on the ssd.

## 2) Dealing with GRUB

### a) Command line:

```
sudo -s
for f in sys dev proc ; do mount --bind /$f /media/ssd/$f ; done
chroot /media/ssd
grub-install /dev/ssd
update-grub
```

Of course, use the correct device for /dev/ssd. The whole disk, not a partition number.

### b) "Recommended repair" magic button in Boot-Repair:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Finally reboot and make sure your bios is set to boot from the SSD.

Comment: I think `/usr/bin/sudo` should always be owned by `root`alias 'uid 0'. How did you move the installation from HDD to SSD? Which method/tool? You seem to have messed with the file ownership (maybe also with the permissions. If you still have a working system on the HDD, you are safe, and can try with a better method. *Please edit your original question to explain* with as many details as possible what you have and what you have done.

Comment: @sudodus i've updated my question. That's what i've done. I still have the working system on my HDD.

Comment: Well, it looks correct, `sudo cp -a` should preserve the ownership and permissions, if you have a target file system that can manage linux ownership and permissions. What file system is there in the target partition?

Comment: I have it set to ntfs

Comment: `ntfs` is a Microsoft file system, and it does *not* manage linux ownership and permissions. Create an **`ext4`** file system in the target partition, and it will work better. Good luck :-)

Comment: Ah, ok. Didn't know that, i'll try that in a sec. Thanks in advance.